# Darken area around jQuery draggable div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm looking for a way to darken all of the area within a container except for a transparent child div. This div is draggable, so the dimmed area would have to move with it. Does anyone know of a way to achieve this using jQuery/CSS? Here is a picture of the effect I am trying to achieve:

[image]

EDIT: SOLVED

See @Robby Cornelissen's answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could do something like [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a6GZr/1/). It relies on an absolutely positioned viewport element with a fixed background. If you click the viewport element, you'll see that it moves while the background stays fixed.

**HTML**

```
<div class="back">
    <div class="overlay">
        <div class="front">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.back, .front {
    background-image: url("http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/51/Swallow_flying_drinking.jpg/1024px-Swallow_flying_drinking.jpg");
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: 0,0;
}

.back {
    width: 1024px;
    height: 623px;
}

.front {
    position: absolute;
    left: 200px;
    top: 50px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 150px;
    z-index: 100;
}

.overlay {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
```